# echo -e \e does not print an escape from bash script on macos

Tags: bash, colors, escape-characters

I just moved to Mac. I'm using a shared shell script that's running in `bash`. The script itself works, however it is written to produce colored output, and that is broken.

Here's the first two lines from the script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo -e -n "\e[0m\e[32mhks>>>\e[2m "
```

- My expectation when running it from `zsh` would be that it produces the output `hks>>>` in bright green.
- However, the output that is produced is:

  ```
  matthiashuttar@mac hks % hks bla
  \e[0m\e[32mhks>>>\e[2m \e[91mfailed to resolve target\e[0m
  ```

I know it's not a `zsh` issue, because I can just execute that `echo` statement as is in `zsh` and it will produce the output in the correct green color.

Can someone point me towards what I am missing?

Comment: The shebang selects the correct shell for you; if you run it correctly, it doesn't matter which interactive shell you are starting it from (any more than `ls` cares whether you run it from Bash, Zsh, or Python).

Comment: The actual symptom suggests that you are running it in a terminal which does not have color support. (The proper fix is to use `tput` instead of bare escape codes.) What is the output of `echo "$TERM"`?

Comment: found a solution - using `printf` instead of `echo -e` worked. just that i do not understand the problem...? 

echo $TERM is xterm-256color

Comment: `echo -e` is nonstandard, but the symptom suggests that you are running the script incorrectly. Running it with `zsh` or `.` will bypass the shebang and force-feed it to Zsh; don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

MacOS ships an ancient version of bash (3.2.x), so bash scripts that work on other systems might not work on macOS. The version of bash on macOS does not support `\e` as an escape sequence in `echo`.

This appears to be a bug in bash 1.x through 3.x, fixed in 4.0. The manual lists `\e` as one of the escape sequences supported by `echo`, but `help echo` lists `\E` and not `\e`. (Though digging into the code I can't see where `\e` and `\E` are treated differently — but experimentally, they are.)

(There's definitely a bug because of the inconsistency. But I think back then supporting only `\E` was the desired behavior, presumably because it was a nonstandard extension and there's a habit in shell circles, mostly coming from command line options, that lowercase letters are standard things and uppercase letters are nonstandard things or modern additions. So the bug was that the manual wrongly listed `\e`.)

`printf` and `$'…'` use different code for backslash escapes, and both recognize `\e` even in bash 3.2.x. Alternatively, you can use an octal escape sequence, which works in all sh-style shells.

So any of the following will work instead of `echo -e -n '\e…'`:

- `echo -e -n '\033…'` (works in most sh-style shells, but some don't support `-e` or `-n` as an option)
- `printf '\033…'` (note that any `%` must be doubled; use `%s` and an extra argument if there's a variable) (works in all sh-style shells)
- `printf %b '\033…'` (works in all sh-style shells)
- `printf '\e…'` (note that any `%` must be doubled; use `%s` and an extra argument if there's a variable)
- `printf %b '\e…'`
- `echo -n $'\e…'`
- `echo -n -e '\E…'`

Comment: `echo -n -e '\E…'` isn't working for me either in macOS' builtin version of bash (v3.2.57), though I haven't tested in the latest version of macOS itself. BTW, another option would be `printf %b '\e…'` (the `%b` format translates escape sequences in the string).

Comment: The Bash on my Mac is "3.2.57(1)-release", and indeed `echo -e '\e'` doesn't work there. But it does work with the exact same version I've compiled from the source on Linux... I don't see a mention of that in the changelog after Bash 3.2 either, so I wonder if the version on Mac just has broken it. The NEWS file lists "nn. The `echo' builtin has a new escape character: \e." as a new feature in Bash 2.0.

Comment: I'd expect the `echo` of macos (and the echo builtin of its sh) to output `-e -n <ESC>…<newline>` for `echo -e -n '\033…'` since it's UNIX certified.

Comment: `\e` is unspecified by POSIX in anycase, `printf '\33'` to print an ASCII-encoded ESC.

Comment: `printf '%b' '\033…'` works in any shell on POSIX systems, not just sh-based ones. Some sh implementations don't have `printf` builtin.

Comment: `printf %s $'\e'` will be standard in the next revision of the standard though.